# Casting the varchar column as timestamp(HH:mm) in hql query or criteria to find minimum time

Tags: hibernate, hql

Can anyone explain how I can cast this query to `timestamp`? having format of `HH:mm` to find minimum time from db column `groundCutOff` .

In my db `groundCutOff` column is in `varchar` format.

```
List<String> locs=new ArrayList<>()
            l.add("rr_1376")
           // l.add("BBY_70")
            //l.add("BBY_87")
            l.add("rr_87")

    Query minCutOffQry=session.createQuery("Select min(groundCutOff) from ArcLocation where loc IN(:locs)")

    minCutOffQry.setParameterList("locs", locs);
                List minCutOffTimeLst=minCutOffQry.list()
                if(!minCutOffTimeLst.isEmpty()){
                    return minCutOffTimeLst.get(0)
                }



Similar to this..

select min(cast(groundCutOff as time)) from ArcLocation;
```

Comment: Can you provide more code? How are you getting results from this query? where are you storing them?

Comment: i have update the query can anyone help me out?

Comment: Post the `locs` list code please, how are you declaring, initializing it?

Comment: i have updated please have a look.

Comment: Is this the code you are using???? there are many  missing `;` !! and `locs` should be declared and initialized before the query.

Comment: its a groovy not required ; and i have posted the at last .

Comment: What's the error you got? can you post the full Stack?

Comment: No error, have u get my question?

Comment: From what I understand, you want to get the minimum value, so better use `query.uniqueResult()` to get a unique value and store it in a String then convert it to time.

Comment: No. I need to get minimum time from the db column

Comment: Please post the format of your `groundCutOff` column.

Comment: its there in varchar format is HH:mm

Comment: I have given example can anyone helpme?